# Finding roots $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ of $x^3+ax+a=0$ (for real $a\neq 0$) if $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}=-8$

Tags: polynomials

This question is taken from AMTI 1994:

> The solutions $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ of the equation $x^3+ax+a=0$, where $a\ne0$ is real, satisfy
> $$\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_3}+\frac{x_3^2}{x_1}=-8$$
> Find $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$.

I tried to solve this by using Vieta's relations and tried to factorize the the equation they gave, but wasn't able to something solid out of that factorization.

Comment: Welcome to the website! Please add your efforts to solve the problem in more detail. Otherwise the question is likely to get downvoted and closed by the community. It is not advised to attach pictures of questions: use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations in future (I have done it for you this time).

Comment: $a=-8$ and roots are $\left(-2,1-\sqrt{5},1+\sqrt{5}\right)$

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \frac{x_i^2}{x_{i+1}} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 \frac{x_i^3}{x_ix_{i+1}}$ where $x_4 = x_1$. this will allow you to compute $a$.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for helping me out ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $x$ is a root, $x^3=-a(x+1)$
$$\implies -8a = \sum_{cyc} x_1^3x_3 = -a\sum_{cyc} (x_1+1)x_3 = -a\left(\sum_{cyc} x_1x_3 + \sum_{cyc}x_3 \right)=a^2$$

Comment: −a∑cyc(x1+1)x3 how did u do that ?

Comment: @AdhirajSinghBrar By replacing $x_1^3$ in the previous expression with $-a(x_1+1)$.